# Using selectors with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I have an object which contains several different NSStrings. When displaying this object, depending on another attribute of the object, I will display one string or another. I have a function defined in the object that takes care of deciding which string to display. So, as a simple example:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString* string1;
    NSString* string2;
    NSString* string3;
    int stringNum;
}

-(NSString)getDisplayString {
    if(stringNum == 1) {
        return string1; 
    } else if (stringNum == 2) {
        return string2;
    } else if (stringNum == 3) {
        return string3;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to create an `NSPredicate` for searching an array of these objects. Is it possible to create one that will search on the results of `getDisplayString`? Obviously I could probably replicate the behaviour of `getDisplayString` within the predicate, but then I'll be doubling up on logic, and probably lead to an error somewhere down the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate with functions or selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569742/nspredicate-with-functions-or-selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"getDisplayString = %@", @"foo"];
NSArray *filtered = [arrayOfMyObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

As a side note, you shouldn't prefix a method name with `get` unless you're going to be returning a value byref via an out parameter.  Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) for more info.

Comment: I assume you meant getDisplayString, not getDisplayName? Fair point about the method name `get` - I've learnt this in the meantime (this question is 8 months old :)

Comment: @alku83 whoops, thanks for catching that :)  And yes, this is old, but I just came across it and it didn't have an answer, and this is good information for people to know.